# UITextfield position changed after insert anything in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The first picture showing textfield position before editing
and the second one showing textfield position after type anything inside it. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Pl explain the question briefly

Comment: After the jump switch to the View Debugger. Are there any exclamation marks?

Comment: @Nandhini - all texts and images shifting to the right once I start typing. this is happening only on landscape orientation

Comment: @matt - no exclamation mark

Answer (score 0):

You can try connect trailing constraint *uiview* where is your *textfield* and bottom view where are your numbers.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know why all texts and images shifting to the right once I start typing. this is happening only on landscape orientation.